# Having an issue getting the GitLab-CE docker container running on VPS

Tags: gitlab

OK, I have a test setup running on a local server that is running like a champ.

I would like to reimplement this on my VPS.  The config file only differs with regards to the mail server section, as the VPS has this enabled, my local server does not.

The issue that is most apparent (perhaps more) is that when I hit my domain:9080 it redirects to the login page, but loses that port information.  My local install does not.

I for the life of me, cannot figure out what I need to change to fix this issue.

To get an idea of what I mean, if the above was unclear, you can goto shadow.schotty.com:9080 and that works perfectly (well obviously not the new user part, as the email isnt setup).  schotty.com:9080 has that redirection issue.

As for the obvious questions for me:

1. Here is the docker publish ports copied from my start script:

   > --publish 9443:443 --publish 9080:80 --publish 9022:22 \
2. No, I did not copy over any existing part of the install on the local host, as I wanted to also document what the hell I did and to ensure that since I am using a newer version I wanted none of the potential issues that crop up with incompatible config files.
3. I did copy my startup script, and modified it appropriately for the volume directories.
4. The only modifications to any configuration files are the mail server section entries.

Thanks to anyone who can toss an idea my way.

Andrew.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Figured a few things out here that should be of help to others.

First off something had changed somewhat since I had done the install on shadow.  But now both are behaving the same since both are on the exact same revision.

To fix the web port across the board, you will need to pick a port to use that the rest of the software suite does not use, nor the obvious of other containers/daemons on the host.  8080 is indeed used, so I chose to stick with 9080.

There are ***2*** places this matters and has a very specific way of needing to be done.  **First** is in the config -- you will need to setup the variable as follows:

```
external_url 'http://host.domain.tld:9080'
```

I am sure many tried stopping there and failed (I sure the heck did).  The **second** spot is in the docker container initialization.  For some reason it *used* to work, but does not anymore.  But the simple fix is just map 1:1 the external port to the internal one.  So in my case I am using 9080, so the following publish must be used:

```
--publish 443:443 --publish 9080:9080 --publish 22:22 \
```

This fixes everything.

Now off to other issues :D